# Create instances of classes that populate forms in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I want to instantiate classes that I have written in Visual Studio 2008 and then populate a listview with these instances which resides in a form that opens up from within Visual Studio. To give you an example let's say we have a `class Employee` within our solution. Using VS Extensibility I would like to open a form in VS that contains a listview. Then I would like to create 100 `Employee` instances populating the listview and be able to edit their properties. Obviously if I change something in the `class Employee` e.g: add an attribute date of birth, then the listview will have to be updated. Can anyone provide any examples or links that would be helpful?

Comment: Which UI technology are you using?  WebForms, WPF, ASP.NET?  They all have different data-binding systems.

Comment: I am using standard winforms and ideally I would like to use the devexpress components.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Upgrade to VS 2010 and use MEF instead of the old VS Ext. MEF is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I am uderstanding the question correctly, you have a form with a ListView, and when you open that form on opening it you create 100 instances of employee so first step.

Start with an array list of Employee.

```
List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
```

Populate this list when the form loads.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       EmployeeList.Items.Add(new Employee());
    }

    // Bind EmployeeList to your ListView
    ListView.ItemSource = EmployeeList;
}
```

If you update EmployeeList and refresh the listview it should update it with the changed information.

Comment: Sorry that is not the question. How do you do the above using the Extensibility Framework so that you load the Employee instances within a form launched from inside VS?